# what would a "modern" TypeCast look like?

Tags: haskell

The class [`TypeCast`](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/typecast.html) dates back to 2004, and is therefore fairly 'old' Haskell (even if still quite brilliant).  My question is: if re-implemented today in state-of-the-art GHC [preferably 7.6, but go ahead, use HEAD if that makes things even better], what would it look like?

If I understand some of the more recent extensions, it may well be that the proper answer is: it is not even needed anymore, just use X.  Knowing the value of X would be nice ;)

Comment: Could you provide a simple example where you think it would be useful?

Comment: You mean [this class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.2.3/docs/Data-HList-TypeCastGeneric2.html#t:TypeCast)?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `TypeCast`; does [`Dynamic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) sit in the same niche?

Comment: Yes, @leftaroundabout I mean exactly that class.

Comment: No, @DanielWagner, Dynamic does not sit in the same niche.

Comment: Thanks to Mikhail Glushenkov, who provided a link to Oleg's page where lots of examples are provided.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with all usages of `TypeCast`, but in what I've been doing recently you can replace it with a type equality assertion (`~`) that you get from the `TypeFamilies` extension. I first saw this in Oleg's stuff [here](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/typeEQ.html#old-implementations):

```
 class  TypeEq x y b | x y -> b
 instance               TypeEq x x HTrue
 instance b ~ HFalse => TypeEq x y b
```

Oleg explains how this voodoo works better than I:

> If the type checker can see that two types t1 and t2 are the same so
>   that the first TypeEq instance can be chosen, the constraint TypeEq t1
>   t2 b simplifies to b ~ HTrue. Otherwise the third argument of TypeEq
>   is unified with HFalse. The word `otherwise' betrays the
>   complementation,`the default case', which is at the core of
>   overlapping instances. We see the first intimations of the usefulness
>   of overlapping instances and of their relation with type equalities.

This is also mentioned on the ["advanced overlap" wiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) in the following snippet:

```
-- instance TypeCast flag HFalse => ShowPred a flag -- before -XTypeFamilies
instance (flag ~ HFalse) => ShowPred a flag
```

Comment: While interesting, your answer is not really to my question: TypeCast has a method, which allows one to 'cast' a value.  TypeEq merely witnesses type-level convertibility.  Sure, it is related, but it only one part of the question.

Comment: The problem is I don't understand in what situations the `typeCast` method is useful or necessary and don't care to hunt one down; if you can provide a usage example I can try to define a new `TypeCast` using `~`. My post was not about `TypeEq` per se, that was simply a demonstration of the technique that can replace `TypeCast`, and you can see both techniques side-by-side in the last code block.

Comment: You can write `f :: (a ~ Int) => a; f = (5 :: Int)`. The old method requires you to repeat the cast at the value-level: `g :: (TypeCast a Int) => a; g = typeCast (5 :: Int)`